# Problems understanding why certain Lua pattern fails

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Consider the following tests completed on the lua cli:

```
Lua 5.2.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2015 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> line = "Conference 1-12345-a.b.c (1 member rate: 32000 flags: running|answered|enforce_min|dynamic|exit_sound|enter_sound)"
```

I'm trying to extract the `12345` from `Conference 1-12345-a.b.c`

This works:

```
> searchtextok = "1%-(%d%d%d%d)"
> print(string.match(line, searchtextok));
1234
```

But this fails:

```
> searchtextok = "1%-(%d%d%d%d)%-"
> print(string.match(line, searchtextok));
nil
```

But I don't understand why.  I'm currently reading [this](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) but if you have any pointers, that'd be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What your first pattern means is *"1, followed by dash, followed by 4 digits"*. The second one is the same, but followed by a *dash*. Since after the *four digits* you have another digit (*1-1234**5**-a.b.c*) and not a *dash*, the match fails.

---

You probably wanted to match 5, not 4 digits. Just change it to:

```
"1%-(%d%d%d%d%d)%-"
```

Comment: yes, i see that now. i'm an idiot!  been looking at this too long

Comment: @Happydevdays, sometimes we get stuck on silly things. Happens to everyone.

Comment: thanks for your patient help.  i love it when people like you are on stackoverflow.  so nice. thanks again.